# Is there any Change by Uploading an App on PlayStore

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services

Is there any difference between the app I upload on Google Developer Console and the App I download from PlayStore?

Because when I install the same apk i upload on Developer Console on my Phone Google Play Services works correctly, but when i install the App from PlayStore the Play Services dont work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: whats the issue try to design the question that make more sense?

Comment: capture logs in case of failure and upload in your question to understand problem.